# I want completely remove Fedora 16 from PC

Tags: fedora

As my title says I want to remove Fedora 16 from my system and reinstall later. I have dual boot to Windows. So can anyone help me to get out of this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have grub installed and Fedora taking care of the dual boot, boot from your Windows installation medium and select the function to get to the command/repair mode.

Then on XP run `fixmbr` and on Windows 7/Vista: `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`

Reboot, this should now work without grub. After that format the Fedora partion from you Windows.